# facebook wall post no image

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I am adding functionality to post to a visitors Facebook wall.

I am using the following code:

```
$path_to_image = "http://projects.kleelof.com/boot_designer/image_interchange.php?c=" . $file_id;
                    $attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
                        'name' => 'The name of your company',
                        'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                        'link' => $path_to_image,
                        'picture' => $path_to_image,
                        'description' => 'this is a description',
                        'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
                        );

                //echo($path_to_image);
                $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

The post appears on my wall, but not the image.

You can see the full process and post it makes by trying the app at: http://projects.kleelof.com/boot_designer - Then select either one of the 2 links.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 1):

I think the path to the image needs to be and actual file system path, and the image will be read and uploaded along with the request for FB to process. Also, it needs to start with a @ to actually upload it.

Comment: Hello, I changed it to 'picture' => "@php/images/" . $file_id . ".jpg", and still a no go. Are there any restrictions on the images that can be uploaded?

Comment: It won't be displayed in feed if the height:width ratio is >3.0 in either direction, and it must be at least 50x50

Comment: My images are 200x186. The results are very inconsistent. Sometimes it woks if 'picture' => URL, sometimes it works if 'picture' => @path_to_image. Maybe someone has some simple code they could post that is working for them. Perhaps I am just missing some obscure little thing.